# Ajax-Success return empty string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a reset password module using ajax but the return value (`console.log()`) from php file is always blank. There is no error also in my php file and I dont even echo empty string. Please help, this is my ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'verify-change-pass',
    data: {_oldpass : op, _pass1 : p1, _pass2 : p2},
    success:function(data) {
        data = data.trim();

        switch(data){
            case "er_no_acc" : 
                $('#grp_oldpass').addClass('has-error');
                $('#feedback_oldpass').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback');
                document.getElementById('msg_oldpass').innerHTML = "*No account found. Please refresh the page to generate new session.";
                //alert('Please enter your username');
                break;
            case "er_oldpass_empty" :
                $('#grp_oldpass').addClass('has-error');
                $('#feedback_oldpass').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback');
                document.getElementById('msg_oldpass').innerHTML = "*Please enter old password.";
                // alert('Please enter your password');
                break;
            case "er_oldpass_invalid" : 
                $('#grp_oldpass').addClass('has-error');
                $('#feedback_oldpass').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback');
                document.getElementById('msg_oldpass').innerHTML = "*Old password does not match.";                 
                // alert('Please enter your password');
                break;
            case "er_pass1_empty" :
                $('#grp_pass1').addClass('has-error');
                $('#feedback_pass1').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback');
                document.getElementById('msg_pass1').innerHTML = "*Please enter password.";
                // alert('Please enter your password');
                break;
            case "er_pass2_empty" : 
                $('#grp_pass2').addClass('has-error');
                $('#feedback_pass2').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback');
                document.getElementById('msg_pass2').innerHTML = "*Please enter password.";                 
                // alert('Please enter your password');
                break;  
            case "er_pass1_tooshort" :
                $('#grp_pass1').addClass('has-error');
                $('#feedback_pass1').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback');
                document.getElementById('msg_pass1').innerHTML = "*Password must be more than 5 characters.";
                // alert('Password too short.');
                break;
            case "er_pass2_tooshort" :
                $('#grp_pass2').addClass('has-error');
                $('#feedback_pass2').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback');
                document.getElementById('msg_pass2').innerHTML = "*Password must be more than 5 characters.";
                // alert('Password too short.');
                break;
            case "er_pass1_toolong" :
                $('#grp_pass1').addClass('has-error');
                $('#feedback_pass1').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback');
                document.getElementById('msg_pass1').innerHTML = "*Password must be less than 20 characters.";
                // alert('Password too long.');
                break;
            case "er_pass2_toolong" :
                $('#grp_pass2').addClass('has-error');
                $('#feedback_pass2').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback');
                document.getElementById('msg_pass2').innerHTML = "*Password must be less than 20 characters.";
                // alert('Password too long.');
                break;
            case "er_pass_notsame" :
                $('#grp_pass1,#grp_pass2').addClass('has-error');
                $('#feedback_pass1,#feedback_pass2').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback');
                document.getElementById('msg_pass1').innerHTML = "*Password does not match.";
                document.getElementById('msg_pass2').innerHTML = "*Password does not match.";
                // alert('Password does not match');
                break;                  
            case "y" :
                    ResetMyPassword(p1);    
                break;
            default:
                alert('Error occured : '+data);
        }


        /* Always put console.log for debugging */
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

And this is my `verify-change-pass.php`

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "Error 404 : Page not found.";
    exit();
}
include("connectdb.php");

$par_uname = $_SESSION['username'];
$par_oldpass = isset($_POST['_oldpass']) ? $_POST['_oldpass'] : ''; 
$par_pass1 = isset($_POST['_pass1']) ? $_POST['_pass1'] : '';
$par_pass2 = isset($_POST['_pass2']) ? $_POST['_pass2'] : '';

trim($par_oldpass);
trim($par_pass1);
trim($par_pass2);
htmlspecialchars($par_oldpass);
htmlspecialchars($par_pass1);
htmlspecialchars($par_pass2);

$count=0;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT acc_hashedpass FROM admin_acc WHERE acc_uname=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$par_uname);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->store_result();
$count = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->bind_result($hashed);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

if($count != 1){
    echo "er_no_acc"; //no username found. check the session if fetched properly
    exit();
}

if ($par_oldpass == ""){
    echo "er_oldpass_empty"; //oldpass is empty
    exit();
}

if(!password_verify($par_oldpass,$hashed)){
    echo "er_oldpass_invalid" . password_verify($par_oldpass,$hashed); //invalid old password
    exit();
}

if ($par_pass1 == ""){
    echo "er_pass1_empty"; //password 1 is empty
    exit();
}

if($par_pass2 == ""){
    echo "er_pass2_empty"; //password 2 is empty
    exit();
}

if(mb_strlen($par_pass1) < 6){
    echo "er_pass1_tooshort"; //password is too short. Must be more than 8 characters
    exit();
}
if(mb_strlen($par_pass2) < 6){
    echo "er_pass2_tooshort"; //password is too short. Must be more than 8 characters
    exit();
}

if(mb_strlen($par_pass1) > 20){
    echo "er_pass1_toolong"; //password is too long. Must be less than 20 characters
    exit();
}
if(mb_strlen($par_pass2) > 20){
    echo "er_pass2_toolong"; //password is too long. Must be less than 20 characters
    exit();
}

if ($par_pass1 != $par_pass2){
    echo "er_pass_notsame"; //password doesnt match
    exit();
}

echo "y";
```

the echo from `verify-change-pass.php`'s first upto the 6th `if` is working and after that, the return value is always an empty string. Please help..

BTW, this snippet works on `localhost` but after I upload it online, the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I need +50 reputation to do a comment, so let me comment via an answer (lol)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Try adding that to the top of your code?

Also, check if

```
include("connectdb.php");
```

has any errors/possible exits inside.

Have you tried echoing something at the very top?

Comment: There is no error in the php file. I also tried to echo right before the `include(connectdb.php)` and the ajax return successful. Also, if i enter the wrong old password, the ajax request return the right value (which is `"er_oldpass_invalid"`).

Comment: I just cant understand why it works properly in `localhost` but not when uploaded online. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove exit function from the code of php file which is been called by ajax
and just print the message you want and try alert the response which you are gettin in success of ajax.
-> You can try with jQuery.trim(data); rather then data.trim();
Hope so it may work.
-> try else if rather then individual if in ajax file of php

Comment: ajax return only the value from first `if` up to the 6th `if`. Other than that, it return an empty string.

Comment: try to use else if rather then all if
if($count != 1){
    echo "er_no_acc"; //no username found. check the session if fetched properly
}
elseif ($par_oldpass == ""){
    echo "er_oldpass_empty"; //oldpass is empty
}

elseif(!password_verify($par_oldpass,$hashed)){
    echo "er_oldpass_invalid" . password_verify($par_oldpass,$hashed); //invalid old password
}.....
else{
echo "Y";
}
And remove all exit(); from condition